# google-cloud/text-to-speech authentification in Vuejs App

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

Hope you're doing well. I'm working on a smal Vuejs Text to Speech app and want to integrate the GCP Text-To-Speech API. By following their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries?authuser=1#client-libraries-usage-nodejs), to authentificate the App, you just need to set the env variable with the right credentials. But I'm still getting 443 Authentification error when call that API on the browser.

Is there someone who have already face the same issues when using any GCP API on a Frontend Applications

Comment: You have an issue with authentication. Did you create a service account with proper role as it described in the documentation https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries?authuser=1#setting_up_authentication ? What OS do you use? Please provide more information about your use case and architecture of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm coding on a Win10 laptop and created the service account with the correct role and download the credentials, set the  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to the jspn file and then call the client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient(). Them the error "You need to pass auth instance to use gRPC-fallback client in browser. Use OAuth2Client from google-auth-library".

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to use the library from the browser when it was designed to be used from a server-side Node.js application. This is explained in more detailed in [this Github thread](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/issues/405).

I would recommend you to dive a bit in this thread, but TL;DR is don't use this library from the browser as that is not yet supported.

Hope you find this useful.